# Tor Browser - start-tor-browser is empty?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

So I was installing the Tor Browser on Kali-Linux and as well as most people I got the "Tor Browser Bundle should not be run as root"-Error. Reading Bugfixes for this i encountered that it's recommended to change the start-tor-browser.desktop file in order to fix the bug. Now i got a problem that I didn't find on the internet yet. The problem is, that the "start-tor-browser.desktop"-file is empty. There is no Code i could change and pasting the code into the document didn't help as well.

Big thanks for your help already.

Comment: Could it be that it looks empty because you have no read permissions for it? (Or is it actually zero bytes long?)

Comment: Did you try to double click the start-tor-browser file? It worked when I did that on my Debian system.

Answer (score 1):

You really should setup a non-root account and run the tor-browser using that account. Editing the .desktop file sounds unsafe to me.

As for the file being empty, I would attempt to re-download the files from the tor project website. Make sure to verify the the integrity.

Comment: Didn't help, downloaded it again. Any other ideas?

Comment: So when I download the Tor Browser for GNU/Linux and look at the start-tor-browser.desktop in a text editor I see the following: http://pastebin.com/sd2nHR54